# Print job "Held for authentication"

Tags: ubuntu, samba, printing, arm

Following the instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/samba-printserver.html), I have installed a Samba print server on an ARM-based [Udoo-quad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDOO) running Udoobuntu 12.04 LTS.

The Samba server is working, and (after setting `guest ok = yes` in the server's `smb.conf`) I can browse the "print$" (Printer Drivers) folder without entering credentials.  I am able to browse to the printer during client-side printer installation (on Ubuntu 13.10), but print jobs do not make it to the server.  They just sit in the client print queue with the status message **"Held for authentication"**.

I have the server configured to allow guest access to printers with the following section in `/etc/samba/smb.conf` (as reported by `testparm`):

```
[printers]
    comment = All Printers
    path = /var/spool/samba
    create mask = 0700
    guest ok = Yes
    printable = Yes
    print ok = Yes
    browseable = No
```

Why does the client think that authentication is required, and what is the fix?

Comment: ["Printing via Samba in 12.04 is broken."](http://askubuntu.com/a/158860/11522)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, this is a problem/complication that was introduced in the version of Samba included in (at least) the initial release of Ubuntu 12.04.  I don't know if there was an update for 12.04 to fix this -- updates don't appear to be available for Udoobuntu.

I resolved it by following [Comment #17](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/+bug/990388/comments/17) from the launchpad bug ["acces denied samba printer shares after upgrade precise"](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/+bug/990388).

Excerpt from server's smb.conf:

```
[global]
   map to guest = bad user
########## Printing ##########
   load printers = yes
   printing = cups
   printcap name = cups
   use client driver = yes

[printers]
   comment = All Printers
   browseable = no
   path = /var/spool/samba
   printable = yes
   public = yes
   guest ok = yes
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700
```

The consensus seemed to be that the key was `use client driver = yes`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, I had the same problem. the status message "Held for authentication"  in the client print queue . To solve this issue, I just install from Synaptic these two packages :
   
- smbclient
   
- cifs-utils

and it works well now for me ! Hope that solves your problem too ...

Comment: The verification in the setup dialog still failed for me but then the actual printing works! Ubuntu 16.10

Answer (score 1):

I setup a windows printer on my Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS Xenial system and my jobs did not automatically start but were "**Held for authentication**". I followed the instructions at [this link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1211404) (mostly)

1. In a terminal window stop the cups printer service:

   sudo service cups stop
2. Edit the printers.conf file:

   sudo vim /etc/cups/printers.conf
3. Near the top of file "/etc/cups/printers.conf" is a line:

   AuthInfoRequired username,password
4. Insert a "#" char in the first column (or, just delete the line).
5. Save edited file
6. Restart cups server:

   sudo service cups start

It worked for me so I thought I would post it even if the question is  years old.